# Sending SIGTSTP suspends entire program

Tags: go

I'm trying to send a SIGTSTP signal to a child process. The problem I'm facing is that sending SIGTSTP to the child process halts my entire program and the caller is unable to proceed with execution of the rest of the program. Here's my code

```
cmd := exec.Command("ping", "google.com")
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
cmd.Start()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
cmd.Wait()
```

Running this code, I get output from `ping google.com` printed on the terminal. When I hit `ctrl-z`, the output is stopped, but the program is not longer able to accept signals or do anything else unless SIGCONT is sent to the child process. Am I missing something? How do I suspend the child process but resume execution of the caller? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Wait](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Wait) waits for the command to exit. Your child process isn't exiting, it's just paused, so `Wait` doesn't return.

Comment: hmm how do I suspend it without being blocked by wait?

Comment: It's not Wait that's blocking. It's io.Copy that doesn't return after the child process is suspended. io.Copy only returns on EOF.